# How to "pause" a foreach loop to output few HTML lines

Tags: php, loops, foreach

So let's say I have an array with key => values I want to output in 2 different HTML lists. Is it possible to do so by using the same loop?

```
<ul>
    // Start foreach and get keys and values**
    <li>$key</li>
    // "Pause" foreach to output the next couple of lines once
</ul>
<ul>
    // Resume foreach
    <li>$value</li>
    // End foreach
</ul>
```

The output should be

- Key 1
- Key 2
- Key 3

- Value 1
- Value 2
- Value 3

Comment: no, the only way to do it in a single loop, would be to save the second <li> array into a varaible, and after the firt loop its over, output it

Comment: @RicardoGarzaV.you should turn that comment into an answer, of course adding in the details.

Comment: @RicardoGarzaV. could we write your comment starting with "yes" ?

Answer (score 2):

Think your looking for something like this:

```
<?php

    $array = array("k1" => "v1", "k2" => "v2", "k3" => "v3");
    $keys = "";
    $values = "";

    foreach($array as $k => $v) {
        $keys .= "<li>" . $k . "</li>";
        $values .= "<li>" . $v . "</li>";
    }

    echo "<ul>" . $keys . "</ul>";
    echo "<ul>" . $values . "</ul>";

?>
```

Output:

- k1
- k2
- k3
- v1
- v2
- v3

Answer (score 0):

you could use 
array_chunk($array, 3, false);  Then iterate through the sub_arrays into the differrnt lists

Comment: Can you elaborate please?

Answer (score 0):

To iterate through the array :

```
foreach(**array_chunk($array, 3, false) as $container**){


                echo '**<div><ul>**';

   foreach($container as $val){

             echo '<li> ' . $val[] . ' </li>';

}

          echo "**</ul></div>**";
}
```